# Individual identity of group members

Tags: c++, doxygen

Is there anything in the doxygen configuration file that determines whether members of a group would be referable with `\ref` *on individual basis*? I would like to be able to refer to class members documented as a group (not to the group as a whole) as to regular class members.

For example:

```
/// \file
/// In particular, blah blah \ref SomeStruct::f1
// Is there a way to make \ref's such as above work without defining anchors?    

/// A very useful struct.
struct SomeStruct {
    ...
    /// \name These functions implement common functionality.
    /// @{
    void f1(); ///< Does X
    void f2(); ///< Does Y
    /// @}
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you sketch a quick example to clarify what you mean? Are you wanting certain group members to go undocumented like the `\internal` tag?

Comment: @JonHarper I have added an example.

Comment: In my opinion it does work, which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: @albert Version 1.8.10

Answer (score 0):

try '\ref SomeStruct::f1' as in

/// \brief look also at \ref SomeStruct::f1 "this"

Comment: How does this differ from what I wrote in the example?